# Python Error Handling Without GOTO

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I am currently getting user input with this line of code:

```
qty = int(input("How many of this item should we start with?"))
```

As one would expect, it throws an error if a value is entered that cannot be converted to INT.

On Error, I would like to prompt "Please enter a whole number" and return to the previous line requesting input.  What is the most "Pythonic" way of achieving this?

Comment: _"What is the most "Pythonic" way of achieving this?"_ In short: Using a `while` loop with `try/except`. See the link above for more info.

Comment: What have you tried already? Have you googled "user input error handling in python" or something along those lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, the most pythonic way is to do the following

```
while True:
    try:
        qty = int(input("How many of this item should we start with?"))
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Comment: Note: The question is tagged for Python 3.x, so `input` is what you want, not `raw_input` (which exists only on Py2).

Comment: Ah ok, updated.

Comment: Does pass bring it back to the prompt again?

Comment: The prompt is back because the `while` loop keeps running, `pass` tells it to do nothing when it sees the error.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you, this will do exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: @NickSentowski `pass` does literally nothing. It's used in empty blocks. The while loop brings it back because `break` will be not reached in case of exception.